# Strange dialog when adding an image to a Q&A

Tags: support, images, uploader

I'm suddenly getting a strange dialog, across all SE sites, when I try to add an image to a Q&A (new or existing).

[image: Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB)]

*[**Editor's note:** for convenience, I've embedded the above image; the author of this question was unable to do so himself, for obvious reasons.]*

None of the controls or links on the dialog work, nor can it be exited. The only way I can clear it from my screen is to click outside of it. It doesn't accept any drag-and-drop action.

This occurs on Chrome, with the latest updates applied.

Oddly, it doesn't manifest with Edge, nor with a new Chrome Incognito window. Those each produce a working dialog. I've tried clearing all data from Chrome, including cookies, cache and local storage. And restarting the browser.

I'm perplexed. Is anyone else seeing this? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Open your debugging console & load the dialog; report any errors or unusual messages that appear.

Comment: Disable your Norton extensions for Chrome - that's what's causing this (or some other anti virus extension for Chrome that you have installed).

Comment: @Oded — Go figure. That was it. How'd you manage to stumble on *that* one? Want to make it an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Shog9 — Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I've seen this reported a few times, just needed to find the duplicates ;)

Comment: @Oded — Good man :-)